# Response Slow when Order BY is added to my SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery, query-optimization

I have the following `job_requests` table schema as shown here

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| available_to.  | integer[]    | NO   |     |         |                |
| available_type | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_at       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have the following query to return a list of records and order them by the `type_of_pool` value

```
WITH matching_jobs AS (
        SELECT
            job_requests_with_distance.*,
            CASE WHEN (users.id = ANY (available_to) AND available_type = 0) THEN 'favourite'
            ELSE 'normal'
            END AS type_of_pool
        FROM (
            SELECT
                job_requests.*,
                users.id AS user_id,
    
            FROM
                job_requests,
                users) AS job_requests_with_distance
        LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_id
    WHERE start_at > NOW() at time zone 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
        AND user_id = 491
        AND (user_id != ALL(coalesce(unavailable_to, array[]::int[])))
    )
    
    
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        matching_jobs
    WHERE (type_of_pool != 'normal')::BOOLEAN
    ORDER BY
      array_position (ARRAY['favourite','exclusive','normal']::text[], type_of_pool),
    LIMIT 30
```

If i remove the `ORDER BY` function, it takes about 3ms but when I add the ORDER BY function, it takes about 1.3seconds to run.

Not sure how do i optimize this query to make it faster? I have read using Indexes and all but not sure how an index will help in this scenario.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may wish to rework your schema to 1NF at least to ensure indices and other usefull DBMS stuff could help you.

Comment: why using `ORDER BY array_position (ARRAY['favourite','exclusive','normal']::text[], type_of_pool)` and not `ORDER BY type_of_pool` ?

Comment: Where do you run your query? DBeaver for example rewrites the query and adds `limit 200`, so w/o `order by` it only fetches a few results. Other tools are similar. Having `order by` however needs _all_ results to be fetched before ordering and then pick the first few. This might be the reason, especially for large tables.

Comment: Did you really mean to generate a cartesian product with this statement: “ SELECT
                job_requests.*,
                users.id AS user_id,
    
            FROM
                job_requests,
                users”? If not, isn’t this entire sub-statement redundant?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.